# SQL query dynamic row generation with composite key

Tags: sql, postgresql, ms-access, composite-key, generate-series

My question is made of 3 parts.

First part:
Is there a way to generate rows based on a value?

E.g:
I want to give each family a number of vouchers based on their `family_members_count`. 
Each voucher should have a unique id:

Base table:

```
id name family_members_count
1  fadi 2
2  sami 3
3  ali  1
```

Result:

```
family_id     name      voucher_id 
1             fadi      121
1             fadi      122
2             sami      123
2             sami      124
2             sami      125
3             ali       126
```

Second part:
Can I control the voucher_id composite key? I want the `voucher_id` to be like this

```
(location)(cycle)(sequence 5 digits)
```

If north = 08 and we are in the second cycle it should be:

```
080200001
080200002
```

... and so on.

Third part:
I need the solution in both MS Access 2010 SQL and PostgreSQL 9.1 SQL.

Comment: As *always*, you should provide version numbers of your software. Assuming current version.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### Question 1

Use [`generate_series()`](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/functions-srf.html). (In the coming version 9.3 look for the key word [`LATERAL`](http://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/Todo).)

```
SELECT id AS family_id
      ,name
      ,120 + generate_series(1, family_members_count) AS voucher_id 
FROM fam;
```

[**-> sqlfiddle demo**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!12/c714f/1)

#### Question 2

```
SELECT id AS family_id
      ,name
      ,location 
       || to_char(cycle, 'FM00')
       || to_char(generate_series(1, family_members_count), 'FM00000')
          AS voucher_id 
FROM fam2;
```

[**-> sqlfiddle demo**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!12/a5a68/1)

- Note the use of [`to_char()`](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/functions-formatting.html) to format numbers as text - and in particular the use of the [`FM` pattern modifier](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/functions-formatting.html#FUNCTIONS-FORMATTING-DATETIMEMOD-TABLE) to avoid leading white space.

#### Question 3

Sorry, I got MS Access out of my system 10 years ago and never looked back. Somebody else might fill in. I doubt it will be as simple.

Comment: sorry i tested and it doesn't do what i want :(, i need the voucher_id to be unique in the whole table :(